Eclipse: Package Presentation -> Flat
In Eclipse, I am trying to change my view from Hierarchical to Flat within the Package Explorer view.
I read another post on how to do this:

Click on 3 dots (View Menu)
Select Package Presentation
Select the Flat option

I tried this, but my view is still in Hierarchical mode.  Any idea what I might be missing?
Thank you.
Dennis
I tried the 3 steps given above.  I expected the view to change from Hierarchical to Flat.

Are you sure you are not mistaking Projects Presentation (first item in the view menu) with Package Presentation (7th menu item)? Be also aware that empty packages are shown compacted as long as in the preferences Java > Appearance the checkbox Fold empty packages in hierarchical layout in Package and Project Explorer is enabled. Please show a screenshot with the option Package Presentation > Flat and the non-empty packages com.example.aaa and com.example.bbb. For me, aaa and bbb are shown as child nodes of com.example or, depending on the preferences, of com > example.

Screenshots would help, as well as indicating which Eclipse version you're using. Hierarchical also won't be exactly the same as the actual folder layout, depending on which packages and classes are actually present. Again, screenshots showing what you're seeing would help.
